# Can you ready an attack against an invisible foe you are not aware of?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, invisibility, readied-action

Our party entered a seemingly empty room. My PC correctly assumed invisible opponents to be in the room, so he readied an action: "If I am attacked, I strike the attacker." Then an opponent attacked him, becoming visible.

Is the PC entitled to attacking the opponent before the opponent's attack strikes home?

The rules seem to imply this:

> The action occurs *just before the action that triggers it* [emphasis mine]. If the
>   triggered action is part of another character’s activities, you
>   interrupt the other character. Assuming he is still capable of doing
>   so, he continues his actions once you complete your readied action. (PHB, p. 160)

My logical problem is that the attacker becomes visible only by attacking the PC.

The readied action interrupts the attack: The attacker has only declared the attack but not actually attacked the PC, he could even be killed without finishing his attack. In that case: Why would he become visible?

Answer (score 5):

- ***If combat hasn't started, your PC can't ready an action.*** Actions can't be readied when not in combat; this is discussed at length in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (25–6).
- ***If the DM said, "Roll initiative," your PC can, on your PC's turn, ready an action.*** However, readying an action doesn't give your PC any senses that your PC doesn't already possess. Unlike, for example, [the trigger of the spell *contingency*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27901/8610), your PC's readied action can't be triggered by a stimulus your PC isn't aware of.

In this case, your PC's readied action *would* trigger, but it would trigger only *after* the attack roll determined if the invisible foe's attack hit and dealt damage or missed. The ready action *I attack the creature* is fine, but the trigger *When I'm attacked* tries to interrupt a process that resists interruption. That is, your PC can't take an action that's predicated upon the foe finishing its action *before* the foe finishes its action.

Unlike movement or casting a spell, making an attack roll is a one-step process, occurring all at once. The *Player's Handbook* on Attack Roll says

> An attack roll represents your attempt to strike your opponent on your turn in a round. When you make an attack roll, you roll a d20 and add your attack bonus. (Other modifiers may also apply to this roll.) If your result equals or beats the target’s Armor Class, you hit and deal damage. (134)

A creature that's affected by an effect like the typical *invisibility* spell does *not* give the defender a window in which to take actions in the quantum time between the creature becoming visible because it made an attack roll and the result of the creature's attack roll still being unknown. The creature's invisible while it's making that attack, it makes that attack by making an attack roll, and that attack roll's result determines if the attack hits and deals damage or misses. (Were this *not* the case, folks wouldn't suffer any penalties for being attacked by invisible attackers—if a typical invisible creature became visible upon, for instance, making the attack roll but *before* the attack roll's outcome is determined, the attacker would be visible when the outcome *is* determined, negating the advantage invisibility typically provides!)

So, yeah, as the defender in this situation, your PC is going to have to learn the result of the invisible attacker's attack roll the hard way—when the attacker's invisibility effect ends because the attacker either dealt damage to your PC or the attacker's attack missed the PC. Only then will your PC's readied action's trigger will be pulled, and your PC can attack.

To be clear, as a benefit of your PC having readied rather than delayed, after the invisible foe's attack is resolved and the foe's visible, this DM would put your PC ahead of the formerly-invisible foe in the initiative order, resolve your PC's readied action, *then* finish the formerly-invisible attacker's turn. Had your PC simply delayed—your PC wanting to make a full attack if the invisible foe reveals itself, for instance—, then your PC would end up in the initiative order *behind* the foe. Whether this is small consolation or shifts the tide of battle depends mightily on the circumstances.

Comment: In our case initiative had already been determined as we had fought some other opponents right outside the room, so readying was perfectly legal.

Comment: I am still reflecting on your answer. Your points are perfectly logical, but the problem with "ready an action" is that it is not entirely logical concerning sequences. I edited the rules quote into my question to point this out: The action takes place "just before the action that triggers it". This is some kind of rules time-travel-paradox and while I can follow your logic, I do not think it is entirely consistent with this wording.

Comment: @Giorin Inconsistency, thy name is the ready action! Seriously, if you've another way to adjudicate this, I'd be *absolutely thrilled* to hear it! I've read, written, and thought a lot about the ready action—[here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122092/8610), for example—, and the only solid conclusion I've reached is, "Expect table variation." (And, on the first comment, if it's okay with you, I'll keep the "No ready outside combat" bullet in the answer because it may be important for other readers.)

Comment: @Giorin (Note that a similar situation occurs whenever a ready action is *Attack a creature* and the trigger is *When I can.* Strictly, the attack would occur *before* it could be made… which is not just impossible but nonsense. It's why I included in this answer the bit about changing the initiative order based on the ready action instead of trying to force-wrap anyone's head around the ugly logical inconsistency. Changing the initiative order *represents* having taken the action, essentially, *before* the trigger could be pulled rather than having it be *literally* so.)

Comment: As said previously your logic is compelling. The only alternative I see is far less convincing, though it fits better with the wording: You could say the readied action has to strike the still invisible attacker with 50% miss chance. I admit that if you think about the logic of this action you get crazy, (You suddenly know where to strike as the opponent *is about* to become visible.) But at least the opponent does not get visible for something he did not yet do.

Comment: @Giorin That's interesting. You could post an answer to that effect and see how it flies. My concern would be *extending* that ruling to other impossible-by-game-logic-but-makes-sense-in-play actions and triggers, like *I attack the creature* with the trigger *when it enters my threatened area.*