# How do readied actions involving movement interact with being charged?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, readied-action

**Situation:**

On her turn, Alice uses the [ready](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm) action.  She specifies the condition "a creature attacks me," and an action that would take her out of melee range (like teleporting away with [*dimension door*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm)).

On Bob's next turn, he [charges](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge) Alice.  The attack he would take at the end of his charge meets the trigger conditions for Alice's readied action, so she teleports away.

What *exactly* happens?

- Does Bob get to make his melee attack before Alice teleports?
- Does it matter whether Alice teleports somewhere that would have been within Bob's original charge range, versus somewhere he could not have charged in the first place?
- If Bob doesn't get to attack, does he still lose his entire full round action for charging?  Or has he only spent a move action if he never gets to attack?  What if he's already moved farther than he could have with a single move action (since you can charge twice your speed)?
- Would it matter if Alice had chosen a different trigger condition for her readied action, like "a creature comes within 20 feet of me?"

Comment: Are you familiar with [this question?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122092/8610)

Comment: I'm about to be!

Comment: That seems to...not exactly *answer* my question, but strongly suggest that there isn't *going* to be a definitive answer.  I guess this can probably be closed as a duplicate!

Comment: I'm comfortable with this question remaining open were it to be edited so that the question was only the first bullet. The second through fourth bullets, though, are, indeed, addressed by answers to the other question.